# Microsoft Azure Function Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-function-app

I am trying to trigger a function app via two separate serviceBusTrigger's(from two different Topics) through the service bus. I tried to add 2 bindings to the function.json with type=serviceBusTrigger but this did not work. Any Idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Hi, what is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

> Triggers are what cause a function to run. A trigger defines how a function is invoked and a **function must have exactly one trigger**. Triggers have associated data, which is often provided as the payload of the function.

You need to create two separate functions with each having its own trigger. If they share common logic then create common function to call it right from both functions.

Comment: I understand but I have two separate functions which send two separate msgs to the service bus with two separate topics. I want the third function to be triggered via either of these to topics. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Service bus auto-forwarding might be an option for you. Function app service bus trigger cannot monitor more than one queue or topic, but you can create a third topic or queue and forward one subscription each from the first two topics to the third topic and then use the 3rd topic to trigger the 3rd function. Let us know if it works - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding